# What's the meaning of elfnn-<arch>.c and elfxx-<arch>.c in binutils/bfd?

Tags: binutils

I am tracing binutils source code.
I found that there are files named `elfnn-<arch>.c` and `elfxx-<arch>.c` in binutils/bfd.
What't the meaning of elfnn and elfxx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where an architecture supports only a 32-bit or a 64-bit ELF-based ABI, the code for that architecture is in a file named elf32-*arch*.c or elf64-*arch*.c, respectively. In some cases, an architecture supports both, but the implementations are very different, so you'll see both an elf32-*arch*.c and an elf64-*arch*.c source file (e.g., ppc, mips).

But some of the more modern architectures, where 32-bit and 64-bit support were developed side by side, share a lot of the implementation (e.g., aarch64, ia64, riscv). In those cases, you'll see an elfnn-*arch*.c source file. This file is a *template*; the build process autogenerates elf32- and elf64- specializations of the file from the template. Still, a lot of code is common to both 32-bit and 64-bit without the need for specialization, so you'll find that code in an elfxx-*arch*.c source file, which is not a template.